# Simple AM-GM Inequality Proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to prove the inequality $a<\sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2}<b$, given that $0<a<b$, by using simple algebra. I proved that $a<\sqrt{ab}<b$ and $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$ fairly easy. For $\sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2}$, I did the following:

$a<\sqrt{ab}$

$0<\sqrt{ab}-a$

$0^2<(\sqrt{ab}-a)^2$

$0<-2a\sqrt{ab}+a(b+a)$

$2a\sqrt{ab}<a(b+a)$

Since $0<2a$,

$\sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2}$.

However, I am aware that there are probably more concise and elegant proofs. I stumbled on this proof by luck so I would appreciate it if someone would explain how they arrived at each step. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Are you asking for an alternative (simpler) proof? Or do you need some clarification about this one?

Comment: I am asking for a simpler proof. Also, I just want to know how you would approach this problem without using the generalized version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
$$(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a})^2 >0$$
Just open and see what you get.

Your proof is similar, you just multiplied both sides of the above inequality by $a= (\sqrt{a})^2$.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks. The main reason I asked this question was because I am trying to improve my proof skills a little by arriving at an elegant (or relatively simple proof) quicker. How did you arrive at this proof?

Comment: @PreciselyT Reverse engeneering: $$\sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2} \Leftrightarrow 2\sqrt{ab} < a+b \Leftrightarrow 0 <a-2\sqrt{ab}+b$$ Now all you need is to recognize the RHS as $(\sqrt{a})^2- 2(\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{b})+(\sqrt{b})^2$.

Answer (score 0):

A way of finding this kind of proofs is starting with the desired inequality and operate with it to reduce it to some inequality that you know is true. But (be careful!), this only works if you can reverse the implication steps (that is, if the implications are "if and only if").

In this case, I'd try this:

$$ \sqrt{ab} < \frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$ ab < \frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$
$$ ab < \frac{a^2 + 2ab +b^2}{4}$$
$$ 0 < \frac{a^2}{4} - \frac{ab}{2}+\frac{b^2}{4}$$
$$ 0 < \frac{(a-b)^2}{4}$$

which is true. But this proves nothing (I must start with the assumed-as-true proposition and build the correct chain of implications). That is doable, thus:

$$ a<b\implies (b-a)>0\implies (a-b)^2>0 \implies\\
\implies a^2 - 2 ab +b^2 >0 \implies a^2 + 2 ab +b^2 > 4 ab \implies\\
\implies \frac{(a+b)^2}{4} > ab \implies \frac{a+b}{2} > \sqrt{ab}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help.